# href with params to link to bookmark in different page

Tags: html

I'm linking from one page to another in my site.  The link is like:-

```
https://example.com/cgi-bin/dashboard/product_catalogue.pl?action=search_by_category&category=kitchen
```

in the following script, my page section has the bookmark id like this

```
<p id='12345'>text in here</p>
```

I can't seem to work out where to put the bookmark trigger in the href.

I have tried:

```
https://example.com/cgi-bin/dashboard/product_catalogue.pl?action=search_by_category&category=kitchen#12345 

https://example.com/cgi-bin/dashboard/product_catalogue.pl#12345?action=search_by_category&category=kitchen#12345
```

and even restructured the whole link:

```
    https://example.com/cgi-bin/dashboard/product_catalogue.pl#12345/search_by_category/kitchen
```

None works.
The #12345 seems to break off the remainder of the hyperlink so the params aren't received by the script that generates the next page.

[what I'm trying to achieve]

In my dashboard, which comprises server-generated pages, I have a product catalogue. eg https://example.com/dashboard/product_catalogue?search_type=search_by_category&category=kitchen

That lists the items in that category
On a specific item, (a photo of that item), I click to go to a server-generated page that shows all the images for that item. (allows editions/uploads etc)
The 'back' button, which is an href to the product_catalogue.pl script, works and I want to add a bookmark, so when we get to the product catalogue, it jumps down to the same listing/place that we were last at before having gone to the images page.
I hope that makes sense.

[/end]

Comment: what is your input and your desired output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of elements in a URI is:

1. Protocol (https)
2. Host (example.com)
3. Path (/cgi-bin/dashboard/product_catalogue.pl
4. Query (?action=search_by_category&category=kitchen)
5. Fragment (#12345)

So your first example is the correct one:

```
https://example.com/cgi-bin/dashboard/product_catalogue.pl?action=search_by_category&category=kitchen#12345
```

You say:

> The #12345 seems to break off the remainder of the hyperlink so the params aren't received by the script that generates the next page.

And that's kind of correct. Fragment processing is all done on the client side. The server doesn't need to know the fragment at all. I'm pretty sure that browsers won't send it to the server.

The sequence of events is this:

- You follow a link that includes a fragment
- The browser removes the fragment and sends the rest of the address to the server
- The server returns some HTML
- The browser displays the page, positioned so that the element with the id given in the fragment is a close as possible to the top of the window

If you're expecting the fragment to be available to a server-side process, then I'm afraid you're out of luck. That's not how it works.

But if you explain what you're actually trying to achieve, then I feel certain that someone here will be able to help you.

Comment: Updated my original question :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  I re-tried my first attempt as you suggested and it does work though, on the first item, it's movement downwards (as per bookmark), is minimal so perhaps I didn't realise it worked. Thank you, again.